# How to determine a .Net program's entry point at runtime?

Tags: c#, reflection

Let's say I have two types in my program, `Foo` and `Bar`. Both have a `static void Main(string[] args)`. To compile this program, a compiler flag `/main:class` is needed.

Is it possible to determine at runtime which of the two types contains the entry point, i.e., to get a `TypeInfo` or `MethodInfo` pointing me to the correct class or the correct `Main` method?

UPD: to be more precise, is it possible to do so from a class library linked to the main application (i.e., without prior knowledge of possible options)?

Comment: `static bool WasStartedFromBar` => `class Bar... Main(string[] args) => WasStartedFromBar = true` ?

Comment: Looking back (how was I started) or looking at another EXE  with ReflectionOnlyLoad?

Comment: You mean like `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().EntryPoint`?

Comment: Have only one entry point "Main" method,then inside that method run your condition code where decide which `Foo.main` or `bar.main` should be executed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An assembly has a `public virtual MethodInfo EntryPoint { get; }`